# Magento 2 Detect Mulltishop

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore

I'm working on a module which needs to detect if there are multiple stores activated .Do someone have any function or know any function present in **Magento** that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at **\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager**. Here is code example

```
protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function execute()
{
     if ($this->storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()) {
         //logic
     }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code but it returns me that the condition is false which is not the case my website doesn't have multiple store

Comment: i tried this it give me test 2              public function multishop(){
  if ($this->storeManager->isSingleStoreMode()) {
      echo 'test';
     }else{
      echo 'test2';
     }
    }

Comment: **isSingleStoreMode** returns true only if ... 1). you have only the one frontend store and 2) if you have choosed the Single store mode under Configuration > General > Single-Store Mode. If you need just check the  multiple condition use **hasSingleStore** method